# "Link this field" the Entity API problem?

Tags: views, entities, files

I am  not sure from where the problem comes, but I am using Entity API and Views integration with Field collection module.

The option Link to entity is not working. Check the images below.

[image]
[image]

Here is a image of the entities I have created and field collections :

[image]

Anyone facing the same issue?

Comment: You are not giving us enough information to help you here. If you want someone to reproduce the issue and see what may be going wrong (assuming it's not a bug of the module) you need to give us the specifics of the setup: what entities you have created and what field collections you are using (possibly a screenshot from admin/structure/field-collections would also help).

Comment: I added a image of the entities I have created and field collections